# Markdown: Regex to find all content following an heading #2 (but stop at another heading #2)

Tags: regex

I have markdown files that sometimes have a single H2, but sometimes also several of them:

```
# This is H1

Some content.

## This is a H2

Some more content.

## This is another H2

Even more content.
```

I'm writing a method in Ruby to extract the content of such H2s. For example, I want to extract the first H2's content. For this, came up with the following regex:

```
^## This is a H2\n\n(.*)\n\n##
```

Sadly, this only works when there is another H2 in the markdown. But I don't know how to make the last part `\n\n##` optional, because adding a `?` to it (`^\n## In Kürze\n\n(.*)[\n\n##]?`) will make it work for markdown with only a single H2, but will capture all following H2s and their contents when there are several.

I hope you get what I mean. I simply want to get the content of a single H2, regardless how many H2 there are.

You can play with my work here: https://rubular.com/r/JVaYHHzglxdLdK

Comment: There are limits to what you can parse using regular expressions, have you looked into actual Markdown parsers?

Comment: I think you want `text[/^## In Kürze\R{2}(.*(?:\R(?!#+ ).*)*)/]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this pattern solves your issue. It matches the content of H2 sections and termintates at the start of H1/H2 sections as well as at the end of the file.

```
/(?:^|\n)##\s[^\n]*\n(.*?)(?=\n##?\s|$)/gs
```

```
(?:^|\n)                // make sure we're at the start of a line
##\s                    // match only H2 tags
[^\n]*\n                // skip the heading name
(.*?)                   // match heading content lazily
(?=                     // use a lookahead as to not consume the next heading's start tag
   \n##?\s              // terminate at H1 and H2 headings...
   |$                   // ...or at the end of the file
)
```

https://regex101.com/r/PB80CH/2

The enabled flags should be **g**lobal and **s**ingleline, can't use multiline mode because of the special logic for H2s that go on until the end of the file.

Comment: Magic! Thank you so much, it works well for my purpose. I added a `+` to `[^\n]*\n` because there can follow several newlines after a heading: https://regex101.com/r/DOqDVB/1. And just for the records: to search for a specific H2, one needs to replace `[^\n]*` with e.g. "This is an H2".

Comment: In Ruby, the `g` modifier is unknown. I don't seem to need it with the `.match` method. Also, the `s` modifier seems to have problems with unicode, resulting in `incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-31J regexp with UTF-8 string)`. I just removed it, too.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852752/ruby-parse-a-simple-markdown-files-having-similar-but-not-equal-structure-an