# Ruby: Parse a simple markdown files (having similar, but not equal structure) and fill contents into object's attributes

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing, markdown

I have a folder full of markdown files. Each of them I want to read into the following Ruby object:

```rb
class File
  attr_accessor :title, :description, :content
end
```

The markdown files usually look like this:

```
# This is the title

This is some description.

And even more description.

## This is an h2

Bla bla.

## This is another h2

More bla bla.

### This is even an h3

Again, more bla bla.

## Again, an h2

etc. etc.
```

This should result in this Ruby object:

```
File:
  h1: "This is the title"
  description: "This is some description.\n\nAnd even more description."
  content: "## This is an h2...etc. etc."
```

To assign the content of the file to the Ruby object's definition, I could simply use a regular expression which would extract `title` (the first H1), `description` (the text right between H1 and the following H2), and `content` (all the rest).

But the files do not always look exactly like this:

- Sometimes, there is no H1

  - (If so, the file name will be used for `title`)
- Sometimes, there is no description
- Sometimes, there is no content

These exceptions can occur in combinations, ie. a file without H1 and description:

```
## This is an h2

Bla bla.

## This is another h2

More bla bla.
```

This should result in this Ruby object:

```
File:
  h1: nil
  description: nil
  content: "## This is an h2...More bla bla."
```

Or a file with H1 but no description:

```
# This is the title

## This is an h2

Bla bla.
```

This should result in this Ruby object:

```
File:
  h1: "This is the title"
  description: nil
  content: "## This is an h2...Bla bla.
```

Or a file with no H1, but a description:

```
This is a description.

Some more description.

## This is an h2

Bla bla.
```

This should result in this Ruby object:

```
File:
  h1: nil
  description: This is a description...Some more description.
  content: "## This is an h2...Bla bla.
```

I wonder whether I can do this using a single fancy regular expression (I'm no expert in that), or whether I should try to somehow split it into several process steps. I asked a similar question here: [Markdown: Regex to find all content following an heading #2 (but stop at another heading #2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616065/markdown-regex-to-find-all-content-following-an-heading-2-but-stop-at-another), but I couldn't get the regex to run properly using Ruby with the exceptions described above.

Any idea how to solve this problem is highly welcome. Thank you.

PS: I also thought about parsing the markdown using a markdown parser and then use Nokogiri or something which would allow me to parse the results. But this feels like way too much overhead for such a basically simple requirement.

Comment: I am a bit confused by all these different examples how the input might look like. What is the expected output for these examples?

Comment: Might want to rethink your class name as well [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html)

Answer (score 1):

Given your examples:

```rb
examples = []

examples << <<-EOS
# This is the title    
This is some description.    
And even more description.    
## This is an h2    
Bla bla.    
## This is another h2    
More bla bla.    
### This is even an h3    
Again, more bla bla.    
## Again, an h2    
etc. etc.    
EOS
 
examples << <<-EOS
## This is an h2    
Bla bla.    
## This is another h2    
More bla bla.
EOS
 
examples << <<-EOS
# This is the title    
## This is an h2    
Bla bla.
EOS

examples << <<-EOS
This is a description.
Some more description.
## This is an h2
Bla bla.
EOS
```

You can do this:

```rb
examples.each do |text|
  text =~ /\A(?:(?:^#(?!#)([^\n]*))?(.*?)(?=^#|\z))?(.*)\z/m
  title,description,content = [$1,$2,$3].map { |s|
    s.strip! if s
    s unless (s && s.empty?)
  }

puts <<-EOS
File:
  title: #{title.inspect}
  description: #{description.inspect}
  content: #{content.inspect}
EOS
end
```

***Note**: The regexp doesn't care about number of consecutive newlines.*

Which gives you:

```rb
File:
  h1: "This is the title"
  description: "This is some description.\nAnd even more description."
  content: "## This is an h2\nBla bla.\n## This is another h2\nMore bla bla.\n### This is even an h3\nAgain, more bla bla.\n## Again, an h2\netc. etc."
File:
  h1: nil
  description: nil
  content: "## This is an h2\nBla bla.\n## This is another h2\nMore bla bla."
File:
  h1: "This is the title"
  description: nil
  content: "## This is an h2\nBla bla."
File:
  h1: "This is the title"
  description: "This is some description."
  content: nil
File:
  h1: nil
  description: "This is a description.\nSome more description."
  content: "## This is an h2\nBla bla."
```

Comment: I took the freedom to add more descriptive details to your post: after each example there is now a description of how the respective Ruby object would look. I don't really get what you're trying to achieve in the `do ... end` block, but there should be something like `File.new(h1: h1, description: description, content: content)`. Maybe you can overhaul the code accordingly? Thank you.

Comment: o_O , adding details to your question in my answer, lol

Comment: You're right, I should put those details into the question. I will move them now.

Comment: Updated the answer to fit the specs.

Comment: Sweet, we're getting very close now. I just added another example that I forgot: `Or a file with no H1, but a description`. If you could update your regex, then I think we're done! ✅